# Ruby Mechanize for Javascript Rendered Form, POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mechanize

Okay so I am trying to do some webscraping of my league on NFL.com/fantasy and the first thing I need to do is login.

I am trying to use mechanize, 
Unfortunately, the form that NFL.com uses for login is rendered with javascript, so simply finding the form doesn't work.

I know mechanize, doesn't find javascript, but maybe I can use a POST of the correct parameters to get past the login screen to the stuff I want?

I tried to follow this answer, but it would only return the the login page again when I attempted:

[trying to POST with ruby mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589260/trying-to-post-with-ruby-mechanize)

```
For form elements:

<input type="text" id="username" name="username .....
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" .....
<div aria-checked="true" role="checkbox" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" value="on"> ....
<button type="submit"


mechanize script:

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("https://www.nfl.com/login")
page = agent.post('http://www.nfl.com/login', {
  "username" => "myusernameredacted",
  "password" => "mypasswordredacted",
  "rememberMe" => "1",
  "submit" => "submit",
  "url" => ""
})
```

Any way, is what I am trying to do possible with mechanize???
(also, can I just copy my session from my browser and use that with mechanize?)

Comment: It seems that the NFL fantasy has a public API (http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/). You might want to use this instead

Comment: i tried but you need a secret key to access your leagues data. The folks over there dont seem too interested in giving me one unfortunately saying its for corpo parteners :(

Comment: Yes, copy the session from your browser that's likely the easiest way.